# Palindrome using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following angular app to check for palindrome. But it does not work for some reason. Where am i going wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/EmOGhR?p=preview

```
$scope.Palindrome = function() {
    var str = $scope.palitext;
    $scope.check == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: `$scope.palicheck = str === str.split('').reverse().join('');` http://plnkr.co/edit/EmOGhR?p=preview

Comment: @PSL: nice answer it worked well... can you tell me if this would work if i have a sentence like "Ah, Satan sees Natasha"? i want the function to ignore case sensitivity and special characters. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result:

```
$scope.palicheck == str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

should be

```
return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

and then:

```
ng-if="palicheck()"
```

or you could do:

```
$scope.palicheck = str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

and

```
ng-if="palicheck"
```

Comment: nice answer it worked well... can you tell me if this would work if i have a sentence like "Ah, Satan sees Natasha"? i want the function to ignore case sensitivity and special characters. how do i do that?

Comment: `tmp = str.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, ''); return tmp === tmp.split('').reverse().join('');`